# XML define restrictions without affecting uniqueness

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Below is an example XML Schema. As you can see, I need to create a large number of elements (`elem001` to `elem999`) where all of them reference another element "param". Note that the attribute ID of param is a key and thus has to be unique.

Now, how can I specify a restriction such that for `elem001`, the attribute "quantity" of the element "param" can only take a given set of values. Similarly, `elem002` to `elem999` will have their own set of values. However, all "param" elements throughout the XML document will have to have a unique ID.

I guess that if I use a type derivation restriction instead of the ref, the uniqueness constraint will not hold anymore over all the "param" subtypes. How do I do it then?

```
<xsd:element name="param">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:extension>
                <xsd:attribute name="quantity" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="ID" type="xsd:int">
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:root>
    <xsd:key name="paramkey">
        <xsd:selector xpath="param/">
        <xsd:field xpath="@ID">
    </xsd:key>

    <xsd:element name="elem001">
        <xsd:element ref="param">
        <xsd:element name="X" />
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="elem002">
        <xsd:element ref="param">
        <xsd:element name="Y" />
    </xsd:element>

    <!-- ... -->

    <xsd:element name="elem999">
        <xsd:element ref="param">
        <xsd:element name="Y" />
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:root>
```

---------------EDIT----------------

I'm sorry, I should have provided an example XML file of my end goal to make it clearer. In the example below, you can see that I have several objects (cars, planes, horses) that contain (among other things) some physical parameters. the attribute "quantity" defines what physical quantity we are talking about: a temperature, fuel level, etc.

Now, I have two requirements:

First, I need to restrict in my schema the allowed physical quantities for cars, which obviously cannot include bloodPressure. Similarly, it doesn't make sense to specify the altitude of a horse (at least for my application...). So I need to specify what are the allowed physical quantities that can be measured on a car for instance.

Second, the id of the params has to be unique among all params. For instance, the id of the plane's altitude cannot be 6, event if the param with id 6 (the horse's blood pressure) has another string value in "quantity"

```
<car>
    <param id="1" quantity="fuelLevel">100</param>
    <param id="2" quantity="temperature">86</param>
</car>
<car>
    <param id="3" quantity="fuelLevel">99</param>
    <param id="4" quantity="temperature">77</param>
</car>
<horse>
    <param id="5" quantity="temperature">123</param>
    <param id="6" quantity="bloodPressure">26</param>
</horse>
<plane>
    <param id="7" quantity="altitude">1000</param>
    <param id="8" quantity="temperature">1050</param>
</plane>
```

Actually, if I could do something like the following, it might even be better, but I think it's even less feasible.

```
<car>
    <params>
        <fuelLevel id="1">100</fuelLevel>
        <temperature id="2">86</temperature>
    </params>
</car>
<car>
    <params>
        <fuelLevel id="3">99</fuelLevel>
        <temperature id="4">77</temperature>
    </params>
</car>
<horse>
    <params>
        <temperature id="5">123</temperature>
        <bloodPressure id="6">26</bloodPressure>
    </params>
</horse>
<plane>
    <params>
        <temperature id="7">1000</temperature>
        <altitude id="8"></altitude>
    </params>
</plane>
```

And another precision: I need the unique id to be an int, so I cannot use a key that associates both the id and the quantity fields.

And by the way, it's very disturbing that this forum doesn't allow me to put some greetings or thanks formulations.

Comment: Do `elem001` etc. refer to `param` elements elsewhere? or do they embed `param` elements as children?  Not at all clear what your XML should look like; impossible to answer your question without a clearer question.

Answer (score 0):

You write *I guess that if I use a type derivation restriction instead of the ref, the uniqueness constraint will not hold anymore over all the "param" subtypes.* Why do you guess that?  (And wouldn't checking the spec or asking a validator be more useful than guessing?)

The key constraint in your pseudo-schema applies to all children of the scoping element named `param`, regardless of their type; why would type restriction change that?

In any case, it's not clear that type restriction and XSD identity constraints have any relevance here:  if you want to constrain the set of `param` elements a given element can point at not by means of the name of the element pointed at, or its location in the document, but on the basis of the value of the `quantity` attribute on the `param` element being pointed at, you have gone well beyond the expressive power of the basic XSD type constructors, and also beyond the expressive power of XSD identity constraints. (Also, for what it's worth, beyond the comparable power of referential integrity constraints in relational database systems.)

XSD identity constraints ensure the uniqueness of values or sequences of values identifiable in a very simple, clearly streamable, subset of XPath 1.0, within the scope of a given element instance in the document.

XSD type definitions are invariably constructed to allow validation of elements against a type in isolation, in a context-free way.  No type-level constraint can depend on a value outside the element or attribute being validated -- if it could, then the action of inserting an element into a particular context, or retrieving it and extracting it from its context, could change its type.  Ask your nearest database or programming-language theorist how they'd like that, but be prepared to catch them when they faint.

Your design sounds horribly, unnecessarily, pointlessly convoluted.  You should almost certainly throw it away and start over.  It is not good as a design for using XML.

At most, it is perhaps useful as an exercise, a way of showing how to handle the situation in XSD, if you are required to blindfold yourself, put your hands in your pockets, and hop on one leg while humming the Marseillaise while others in the room shout Dada poetry into your ears and slip banana peels under your foot.

In that spirit, consider the following XSD 1.1 schema, which defines a vocabulary meeting the requirements you describe in prose (and ignoring your pseudo-code, since I cannot figure out what it is trying to do).

We define elements `root`, `param`, and `elem001` through `elem005`, leaving the other 994 as an exercise for the reader.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/jacques"
  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/jacques"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

  <xs:element name="root" type="tns:root">
    <xs:key name="parameter-uniqueness">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//tns:param"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
    </xs:key>    
  </xs:element>
```

As you see, the root element enforces the uniqueness of `param/@ID` values.

```
  <xs:element name="param" type="tns:param"/>
  <xs:element name="elem001" type="tns:elemNNN"/>
  <xs:element name="elem002" type="tns:elemNNN"/>
  <xs:element name="elem003" type="tns:elemNNN"/>
  <xs:element name="elem004" type="tns:elemNNN"/>
  <xs:element name="elem005" type="tns:elemNNN"/>
```

The `param` and `elemNNN` elements are not very interesting. Note that `elem001` through `elem005` all share the same type.  Type restriction would not be impossible here, but it also does not help achieve what you say you want.

```
  <xs:complexType name="param">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:double">
        <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:int"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="elemNNN" mixed="false">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!--* Whatever common structure we want here *-->
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
              processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>    
    <xs:attribute name="param" type="xs:int" use="required"/>    
    <!--* Whatever common attributes we want ... *-->
    <xs:attribute name="color"/>    
    <xs:attribute name="shape"/>
    <xs:attribute name="height"/>
    <xs:attribute name="postal-code"/>
    <!--* ... *-->
  </xs:complexType>
```

All the interesting action is in the type of the root element.  Its content model is straightforward:  some parameters and then the `elemNNN` elements:

```
  <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="tns:param" minOccurs="0"
                  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>      
      <xs:element ref="tns:elem001"/>  
      <xs:element ref="tns:elem002"/>  
      <xs:element ref="tns:elem003"/>  
      <xs:element ref="tns:elem004"/>  
      <xs:element ref="tns:elem005"/>
    </xs:sequence>
```

The constraints on the `param` elements that a given element can point at cannot be formulated on the type of the pointing element, since the `param` elements are outside the pointing element.  (If they were embedded, as your pseudo-schema seems to suggest, things would be very different, but no pointing would be involved.)  So they must be formulated in the declaration of some ancestor element which has both the pointing elements and the param elements as descendants.  Here, we do it on the root element.

Let us allow `elem001` to point only at `param` elements whose `quantity` attribute is between -323 and +2387, inclusive:

```
    <xs:assert test="for $e in .//tns:elem001, 
      $pref in $e/@param,
      $p in .//tns:param[@ID = $pref],
      $q in $p/@quantity
      return 
      ($q gt -324 and $q le 2387) (: in range -323 to 2398 :) "/>
```

Element `elem002` is permitted to point only at `param` elements whose `quantity` attribute is a positive prime number less than 15:

```
    <xs:assert test="for $e in .//tns:elem002,  
      $pref in $e/@param,
      $p in .//tns:param[@ID = $pref],
      $q in $p/@quantity
      return 
      ($q  = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)) (: prime lt 15 :) "/>
```

The constraint on `elem003` is that its `param` elements must have a `quantity` value equal to 0, 1, 7, 8, 14, 15, ...:

```
    <xs:assert test="for $e in .//tns:elem003,
      $pref in $e/@param,
      $p in .//tns:param[@ID = $pref],
      $q in $p/@quantity
      return 
      ($q mod 7 lt 2) "/>
```

And so on.

```
    <xs:assert test="for $e in .//tns:elem004,  
      $pref in $e/@param,
      $p in .//tns:param[@ID = $pref],
      $q in $p/@quantity
      return  
      ($q gt 2387)  "/>

    <xs:assert test="for $e in .//tns:elem005,
      $pref in $e/@param,
      $p in .//tns:param[@ID = $pref],
      $q in $p/@quantity
      return 
      ($q le -324)

      "/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This schema accepts the following input as valid; it is easy to make it invalid by making a pointer point to a `param` with an inappropriate `quantity` attribute, or by changing the `quantity` values on `param` elements which are actually pointed to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/jacques jacques.xsd" 
  xmlns="http://example.com/jacques">
  <param ID="1" quantity="23">2</param>
  <param ID="14" quantity="3">876.4</param>
  <param ID="31" quantity="44423">833838</param>
  <param ID="-44" quantity="23">111</param>
  <param ID="-127" quantity="-0333">22223.33</param>
  <param ID="22" quantity="8">2</param>
  <param ID="12" quantity="23">1</param>
  <elem001 param="1">
    <p>This is some sample data.</p>
  </elem001>
  <elem002 param="14">
    <p>Just hanging around here.</p>
  </elem002>
  <elem003 param="22">
    <p>No worries.</p>
  </elem003>
  <elem004 param="31">
    <p>How you doin', bro?</p>
  </elem004>
  <elem005 param="-127">
    <p>Hasta la vista, baby.</p>
  </elem005>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
I'm sorry for now having provided an example. Mistake corrected. I edited my initial post at the bottom.
I didn't know about the xs:assert before. I guess the solution to my problem is in that direction.